# When I type "npm run generate" in my code block vscode out and deleting the letter i

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, code-generation, auto-generate

When I type "npm run generate" in my code block, codegen generates my graphql file automatically. But while generating vscode is freaking out and deleting the letter i. When I make a new change, I have to constantly change it. Has anyone encountered such a problem before?

My codegen.yml file looks like this:

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:3000/graphql"
#schema:
#  - https://***/graphql:
#      headers:
#        Cookie: "***"
documents: "src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
      - "fragment-matcher"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

[image: this way it deletes the letters according to her own head]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably something on your env, replacing `io` with `O`.
Could you create a minimal isolated reproduction of this issue, maybe via [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?